# Not able to navigate to another screen using NavigationLink + SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to navigate from one screen to other. So I used NavigationLink. Whenever I click on button, nothing happens, Not even print statement is printing in console.

Here is the code:

```
struct _LoginView: View {

  var body: some View {

    Color.green
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .overlay(
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {

                Image("Bg")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 130, height: 130, alignment: .center)
                    .clipShape(Circle())

                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(destination: _LoginViewMain()) {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("button clicked")
                    }) {
                        Text("SIGN IN")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                    .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                        )
                    }
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: _LoginViewMain()) {

                    Button(action: {
                        print("btn cliecked")
                    }) {
                        Text("SIGN UP")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .font(.system(size: 18))
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)

                    }
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
            .foregroundColor(Color.green)
            .padding([.top, .bottom], 100)
    )
  }

}
```

Could someone help me to know the reason why the navigation link is not getting trigged?

Answer (score 1):

You must embed NavigationLink into a NavigationView. Do try the snippet below.

```
struct _LoginView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Color.green
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .overlay(
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {

                        Image("Bg")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFill()
                            .frame(width: 130, height: 130, alignment: .center)
                            .clipShape(Circle())

                        Spacer()


                        Button(action: {
                            print("button clicked")
                        }) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: _LoginViewMain()) {
                                Text("SIGN IN")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                        .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
                                )
                            }
                        }


                        Button(action: {
                            print("btn cliecked")
                        }) {
                            NavigationLink(destination: _LoginViewMain()) {
                                Text("SIGN UP")
                                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                                    .font(.system(size: 18))
                                    .padding()
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)

                            }
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .cornerRadius(25)
                        }
                    }

                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 30)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .padding([.top, .bottom], 100)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I'm not able to navigate to next screen...I embedded NavigationLink into NavigationView

Comment: And another thing, you have to embed your text label into the NavigationLink not the button. Hope you did so. Did you?

Comment: Yeah, that way it is working now....but I've tried in a demo with Button embedded in NavigationLink and it was working. but here it is not working

Comment: Like this: `var body: some View {
        HStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: TableView()) {
                Button(action: {
                    print("Button is clicked")
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Submit").font(.headline).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    
                }.cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)
                
            }
        }
    }`